# iPhone to Java EE remoting

Tags: java, iphone, web-services, ios, remoting

I was looking for some opinions on the best remote method invocation practices when developing iPhone applications that communicate with Java (java EE) servers.

Many iphone applications these days typically talk to a server back end. I typically prefer to write my servers in java using some Spring libraries. So far I have not found or stuck to a definitive practice for iphone->java server communication.

What are some technical solutions and libraries that you have used to implement this kind of client-server communication?

One thing I always keep in mind is that I want the communication protocols to be simple so that multiple platforms can be added for example, in future adding Android and possibly Blackberry clients, that can use the same protocol to talk to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently doing this for work as well. Our backend is Java EE (with Spring) and then of course the front end is iOS. We use JSON as the payload format, as Knubo suggested. All of our web services are also RESTful to make dealing with URL construction and authentication on the phone easier.

I would highly recommend you check out [RestKit](http://restkit.org/), which is a pretty comprehensive framework that allows you to easily integrate your [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), JSON-based web services with CoreData. We also use [YAJL](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc) for parsing JSON manually in the rare cases where that is necessary.

Thus far, that tooling has made it a breeze to work with our web services.

Comment: If one of the provided answers helped you out, please mark it as the accepted answer. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with JSON. If you want to use Spring, go with restful webservices. Do some googling on "webservices restful spring json" (without the quotes) and you'll get some pointers.

JSON will suit you fine with other languages as well. I've written an iPhone application that uses JSON, and that was quite easy with the use of
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework. I'm pretty sure that both Android and Blackberry should be capable of reading JSON just fine as well.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have put this iPhone application under an MIT license and you can browse the code on google code:

http://code.google.com/p/accountadmin/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fiphone%2FFrittRegnskap%2FClasses

Comment: Agreed, RESTful routes serving JSON is my default suggesting for any mobile API at this point. Easy to work with on multiple platforms (including in a browser) and reasonably efficient to send over the network. In general JSON seems to be significantly faster to parse using any of the open source parsers than XML with NSXMLParser. If you want to go through the work of serving binary plists then that should be faster still.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework is really useful.